# Using LINQ to flatten lists while capturing the index

Tags: c#, .net, linq, indexing, flatten

I have a `List<List<List<Foo>>>` and I would like to flatten this to `List<new {Foo, Ndx}>` where Ndx is the index from the outermost List.  For example, if I had something like:

```
new List(){
    new List(){
        new List(){ new Foo("a"), new Foo("b")},
        new List(){ new Foo("c")}},
    new List(){
        new List(){ new Foo("x"), new Foo("y")}}}
```

I might end up with Ndx of 0 for "a", "b", & "c" and 1 for "x" & "y".  Someone have a LINQ solution?

Comment: *"I have a List<List<List<Foo>>>"* ... Wow, surely there's a better structure for this?

Comment: @Yuck: Is Yuck merely your name or also your opinion here? :)

Comment: @StuartGolodetz It's actually my given name; my parents were very cruel.

Comment: Didn't mean that rudely btw - was just struck by the fact that you were expressing distaste for the data structure and following it up with "- Yuck" :)

Comment: How many items should be in final result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit fiddly, but you can do it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<Foo,int>> result =
    tree.SelectMany(
        (L1,i) => L1.SelectMany(
            L2 => L2.Select(
                k => Tuple.Create(k,i)
            )
        )
    );
```

A compilable version is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Foo
{
    public string s;

    public Foo(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tree = new List<List<List<Foo>>>
        {
            new List<List<Foo>>
            {
                new List<Foo> { new Foo("a"), new Foo("b") },
                new List<Foo> { new Foo("c") }
            },
            new List<List<Foo>>
            {
                new List<Foo> { new Foo("x"), new Foo("y") }
            }
        };

        IEnumerable<Tuple<Foo,int>> result = tree.SelectMany((L1,i) => L1.SelectMany(L2 => L2.Select(k => Tuple.Create(k,i))));
        foreach(var si in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(si.Item1.s + ' ' + si.Item2);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: As @sll points out, this solution requires .NET 4 due to the use of `Tuple`. It wouldn't be too hard to adapt though if necessary.

Comment: @sll: Fair enough. I confess I've always been a C++ programmer (I just started with C# earlier this year), so what's new or not in the latest .NET has been somewhat lost on me.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var l = new List<List<List<Foo>>>(){
            new List<List<Foo>>(){
                new List<Foo>(){ new Foo("a"), new Foo("b")},
                new List<Foo>(){ new Foo("c")}},
            new List<List<Foo>>(){
                new List<Foo>(){ new Foo("x"), new Foo("y")}}};

var q = l.SelectMany ((x, i) => 
            x.SelectMany (y => 
                y.Select (z => new { z, i })));
```